# Quuiero agregar una referencia desde Reference Manager en Visual Studio 2019, pero no me sale la opción Assemblies

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy creando un windows form en C#, y necesito agregar la referencia "System.Configuration" pero no me sale la pestaña de "Assemblies". ¿Cómo la agrego?

Comment: Podrias especificar por favor en que se basa tu proyecto? netcore o net framework? en netcore cambia bastante por eso

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví por mí mismo. El problemafue el tipo de Class Library que estaba utilizando, debía ser de tipo "Net.Framework"

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).